# javascript - I cannot seem to pass a filename into a var and get it to load

Tags: javascript, html

I have now edited this question to reflect my new code that works but it doesn't work in IE, only Mozilla, can anyone help?

JS:

```
function loadXML(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, false);
  xhr.send(null);
  return xhr.responseXML;
}

   function loadTest(filename){

    var stylesheetTest = loadXML("stylesheet.xsl");
    var fileTest = loadXML(filename);

    if (typeof (XSLTProcessor) != "undefined") {
    var processor = new XSLTProcessor();
    processor.importStylesheet(stylesheetTest);
    var result = processor.transformToFragment(fileTest, document);
    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(result);
  } else
    document.write(xmlDoc.transformNode(stylesheet));   
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form1">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Enter a filename:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="fileName" onclick="loadTest(this.form.value1.value);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<div id="results">
</div>
```

Much obliged for any help or tips! Thanks to Asad for help offered already.

Comment: What does not work in IE, what exception do you get? Afaik IE does not support `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to reload the document:

```
function changeFileNme(x){
    xmlDocValue = new String(x);
    xmlDoc = loadXML(xmlDocValue);
}
```

Comment: ah...thanks! why is this? Is it to re initiate the var holding xmlDocValue? It still doesn't work though!

Comment: @user1360809 Yes. The value of `xmlDoc` does not change automatically when you change the value of `xmlDocValue`

Comment: @user1360809 Large chunks of code are supposed to go into your question, not in comments.

Comment: @user1360809 You can edit your question. You're absolutely right, **don't** ask a new one. This also has the benefit of bumping your question to the front page, where people are likely to find it and try to assist you.